# while Zipping UnauthorizedAccessException was caught

Tags: c#

Trying to Zip the .txt files but while zipping the following exception occurred @ line `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dir, dir);`

> Access to the path 'C:\Pa_EXPORT\VFT\Archive' is denied

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Today;
int FileCnt;
var dir = "C:\\Pa_EXPORT\\VFT\\Archive";
string LogFile = "C:\\Pa_EXPORT\\VFT\\Log";
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
var FilesToZip = info.GetFiles("*.txt");

if (FilesToZip.Count() > 1)
{
     FileCnt = FilesToZip.Count();

     foreach (var Files in FilesToZip)
     {
         ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dir, dir);
         string LogMsg = DateTime.Today + "\n" + Files + "Deleted from the path" + dir;
         File.Delete(dir + "\\" + Files);
         LogMsg = DateTime.Today + "\n" + Files + "Compressed from the path" + dir;
         File.WriteAllText(LogFile + "log.txt", LogMsg);
     }

     DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) CreateFromDirectory method needs a source file name and a destination file name. Destination file name needs to be something like foo.zip.